# How to keep "select" as item[0] for drop down list

Tags: c#, webforms, controls

I have a drop down list in UpdatePanel_2, it gets populated when Button_1 is clicked in UpdatePanel_1,

when DropDownList is populated, it removes my "Select" item not sure why,

My Drop down list markup is,

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drop1" runat="server" >
              <asp:ListItem Text=" Select " />   
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is how I am populating it,

```
using (SqlDataSource sqlds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), SelectCommand()))
            {
                drop1.DataSource = sqlds;
                drop1.DataTextField = "UserName";
                drop1.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` to your `DropDownList`

but if you are populate `DropDownList` again and again you can do as below

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drop1" runat="server" ondatabound="drop1_DataBound" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
protected void drop1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drop1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select ", ""));
}
```

Or even below will work

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drop1" runat="server" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
using (SqlDataSource sqlds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), SelectCommand()))
{
    drop1.DataSource = sqlds;
    drop1.DataTextField = "UserName";
    drop1.DataBind();// insert after DataBind
    drop1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select ", ""));
}
```